# Exception in thread "Loading Sources" al iniciar Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, android

He instalado el SDK de Android para poder crear un emulador y probar una app y no hay manera de que el Android SDK Manager me muestre los paquetes disponibles para poder instalarlos. Al abrirlo solo me muestra los paquetes que se han instalado por defecto con Android Studio.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

El error que me aparece en el terminal al ejecutar el SDK Manager desde fuera de Android Studio es el siguiente:

```
(Android SDK Manager:21996): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed

(Android SDK Manager:21996): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed

Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurityManager.java:65)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Cipher.java:2595)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Cipher.java:2619)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:602)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:574)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:460)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:1074)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:353)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:41)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:582)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Class.java:291)
at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Provider.java:1844)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Provider.java:1820)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/GetInstance.java:236)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/GetInstance.java:164)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContext.java:166)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:202)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openWithHttpClient(UrlOpener.java:369)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openUrl(UrlOpener.java:188)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:298)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:681)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:603)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetchXmlUrl(AddonsListFetcher.java:272)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:137)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsListInTask(PackageLoader.java:465)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.access$200(PackageLoader.java:52)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$3.run(PackageLoader.java:435)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:140)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView.startTask(ProgressView.java:162)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressViewFactory.start(ProgressViewFactory.java:46)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsList(PackageLoader.java:432)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$1.run(PackageLoader.java:238)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:91)
... 41 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixPath.java:75)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixPath.java:69)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixFileSystem.java:280)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Paths.java:84)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:254)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:49)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:82)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:79)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:78)
... 41 more
```

He probado a instalar el SDK tanto de forma independiente como junto con Android Studio. También he probado a activar la opción **Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...** que hay en **Tools > options** pero nada.

El sistema operativo es Ubuntu 16.10 y la versión de java que utilizo es OpenJDK 9:

```
openjdk version "9-Ubuntu"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b134-2ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b134-2ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

**EDITO:**

Este es el log que me muestra el SDK Manager. La última URL se queda en estado **Fetching** y no se completa.

```
Fetching http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
```

He probado a acceder a la URL desde mi navegador y puedo ver el documento XML sin problemas.

Comment: Probablemente connectado con [el mismo error reportado  en askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/questions/845375/android-sdk-manager-exception-on-lubuntu-64bit) (no solucionado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Problema resuelto! El error lo estaba causando Java 9. He visto en varios foros gente con el mismo problema y todos tenían instalada la versión 9 de Java. He probado a desinstalarla y volver a Java 8 y problema resuelto. Ya puedo actualizar y descargar nuevos paquetes sin problema.

Answer (score -1):

Un detalle importante es que mencionas que tienes la opción

**Force https://**... sources to be fetched using http://...

Si esto no funciona probablemente estas dentro de un proxy, verifica si esto es asi, te sugiero configures el proxy y especifiques las credenciales necesarias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si quito esa opción se ocultan los paquetes instalados y la ventana se queda en blanco. He editado la pregunta añadiendo el log del SDK Manager. Parece que no es capaz de finalizar una de las peticiones.

Comment: Si no descarga los paquete posiblemente es la conectividad, revisa si estas dentro de un proxy.

Comment: No estoy dentro de un proxy. Lo de marcar la opción para forzar el https fue porque lo vi en un post, pero tampoco funcionó.